# Internal server error when posting to route from nodejs backend with express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am new to `nodejs` and wanted to learn how to connect to my preexisting database on my `localhost` and add `tuples` into it. I decided to go with `nodejs` for backend and `express` to help set up my routes. When I try to do a `POST` request, I am getting the error `ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'firstName' in 'field list'`. I have restarted my database and `nodejs` application, checked to make sure I had the correct spelling for my `name` field, and also checked if my `routes` were the same in my `form.html`. I will put my `form.html` and also my `node.js` code for the the `POST`.

`node.js`

```
app.post("/usercreate", (req, res) => {
  console.log("first name is " + req.body.create_fname);
  console.log("last name is " + req.body.create_lname);

  const firstName = req.body.create_fname;
  const lastName = req.body.create_lname;

  const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    database: "employees"
  });

  const queryString =
    "INSERT INTO departments(firstName, lastName) VALUES(?,?)";
  connection.query(
    queryString,
    [firstName, lastName],
    (err, results, fields) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Could not post" + err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
        return;
      }
      console.log("Inserted new department with dept_name");
      res.end();
    }
  );
});
```

`form.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>SQLFORM</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Fill Form Below</div>
    <hr />
    <form action="/usercreate" method="POST">
      <input placeholder="First Name" name="create_fname" />
      <input placeholder="Last Name" name="create_lname" />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems like that's an error from MySQL, are you sure there is a `firstName` column that is named _exactly_ that?

Comment: my column names are `dept_no` and `dept_name` in my database

Comment: Thank you so much @jakerella that was the problem!